# Android How to get First Activity's Handler data into third activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

---

I have three activities A,B,and C.

---

I go from Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C
Now currently Activity C is displaying and Activity A is bottom on Activity Stack
then I provide some inputs to Activity C through which the another thread send some data to Handler of Activity A.

---

Now I want to receive that data on my Activity C.

---

Can any possible solution ?
Should I use intent and if yes then can u give me appropriate guidance ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If data is for decision purpose only then you can use `static` or `SharedPreference` and use handler to notify that the data has come or changed.

Comment: If I do not want to use shared preference then and how static variable can be use because i donot know when will the data arrived on firstactivity handler..

Comment: you need to set the handler of activity C to activity A thru setter and when you get the data in activity A's handler, notify activity C thru it's handler.....

Answer (score 1):

Pass data through intents as extras. USe .putExtra and just pass from B to C.

Comment: If I am already on Activity C then how can I pass data of Activity A to Activity C through Intents.(I know that if we start Activity from one Activity then we can pass intent through StartActivity(Intent) but here our Activity already started..)

Comment: You can send a broadcast, but you probably shouldn't be running a long executing Thread as a member of an old Activity. Look into a service and then either bind the service and set a listener in Activity A and C, or send broadcasts on certain events.

Comment: i have another thing to ask i didn't use any broadcast yet then for this purpose it is only the solution .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to pass massages from one to activity to the other. You can use a singleton class to do that. Here is a skeleton you can use

```
// Singleton Class for message passing
public class Messenger {

    private static Messenger instance = new Messenger();

    public static Messenger get() {
        return instance;
    }

    private String  theMessage_;

    // Default Constructor
    private Messenger() {
    }


     // Setter to set the message you want to pass
    public void setMessageToBePassed(String myMessage){
        theMessage_ = myMessage;
    }


    // Getter to get the message that is passed to you
    public String  getMessage(){
        return theMessage_;
    }

}
```